# wp_ajax returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, wordpress

Good morning,

Sorry if this has been posted before. My reason for posting another is that none of the solutions on the other posts has resolved my issue.

Whenever I post to my `admin-ajax.php` URL, I get a `400 Bad Request` response. I've been trying to make this work for ages now.

Here's the PHP end of the code:

```
<?php

  if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

  define("PLUGIN_VERSION", '0.0.02');

  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'findajob_load_scripts');
  function findajob_load_scripts() {
      global $wp;
    $current_page = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
    wp_register_style('findajob-css', plugins_url('/findajob.css', __FILE__), array(), PLUGIN_VERSION);
    wp_register_script('findajob-js', plugins_url('/findajob.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), PLUGIN_VERSION, true);
      wp_localize_script('findajob-js', 'findjob', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 'current_page' => $current_page));
  }

  add_shortcode('findajob-form', 'findajob_shortcode');
  function findajob_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
      global $wp;
      $current_page = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));
      wp_enqueue_style("findajob-css");
      wp_enqueue_script("findajob-js");
      ?>
      <form type="POST">
          <button name="Test">Click me!</button>
      </form>
      <?php
  }

  add_action("wp_ajax_findajob_admin_ajax", "findajob_admin_ajax");
  add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_findajob_admin_ajax", "findajob_admin_ajax");
  function findajob_admin_ajax() {
      global $wpdb;
      echo "testing";
      wp_die();
  }

?>
```

And here is the ajax request in JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('button[name="Test"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: findjob.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            // contentType: 'text',
            data: {
                'action': "send_form"
            },
            success: function(Resp) {
                alert(Resp);
            },
            error: function(a, b, c) {
                console.log(a, b, c);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm hoping that somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action paramter inside your ajax call has to be the name of your Ajax action.

```
add_action("wp_ajax_findajob_admin_ajax",....
```

you have to name your action as:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('button[name="Test"]').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: findjob.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            // contentType: 'text',
            data: {
                'action': "findajob_admin_ajax"
            },
            success: function(Resp) {
                alert(Resp);
            },
            error: function(a, b, c) {
                console.log(a, b, c);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, you have no idea how long I've been banging my head against the wall on this one...